# pick data from a chosen tab in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem. I have a file with many tabs. the name of each tab is a country and in the tab there are various data about the country. I would like to create an interface tab, where the user can put the country name in a cell (eg "France" cell A1), the data item in another cell (eg "Births") and the interface will give the time series of the data item ("Births" in my example). Is there a way to do it using Excel and not VBA? I can do it with VBA, but I need an Excel-only way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the data structured?  Is "Births" a column heading?  Are the time series all the same length?  Start by looking at `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, the data is formatted as a columns. In the first column are the years. In the second column Births, in the third number of children etc etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With France in A1 and Births in A2, you would need a named range with worksheet scope called Births on the France worksheet. Then you can use the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to piece the address together.

```
=indirect("'" & a1 & "'!" & a2)
```

But you probably do not want to make all of those named ranges for every worksheet. You will have to provide a better description of your data layout on each worksheet for more specific assistance.

Comment: Good move including the single quotes.

Comment: They do no harm if included and unnecessary but break the formula if required and absent. I try to stay in the habit of including them whether the particular situation needs them or not.

Comment: thanks  a lot for the reply. the data within each tab is formatted as columns. In the first column are the years. In the second column Births, in the third number of children, there are many such columns in each tab, so creating ranges could take some time. Please let me know if you need more info for more detailed help

Comment: Well, unless you want an array of all of the Births, you would need another cell for the year.